# Picking date from id element in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, date

I'm trying to pick a date from an id with this code. Actually I'm able to get correct data only if I manually declare it the date, so I guess that mistake is in document.getElementById('fromDate').value;

```
<input id="fromDate" type="date">
<input id="toDate" type="date">

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Invia richiesta</button>

<p id="stampain"></p>
<p id="stampafi"></p>
<p id="stampali"></p>

 <script>

    // Define the data start
    var datastart = document.getElementById('fromDate').value; // doesn't pick data
    // var datastart = '30/03/2017'; // manually
    var datastart1 = datastart.split('/').reverse().join('-');
    var ds = new Date(datastart1);
    var start_dt = ds.toISOString().substring(0,10);

    // Define the data start
    var dataend = document.getElementById('toDate').value; // doesn't pick data
    // var dataend = '30/03/2017'; // manually
    var dataend1 = dataend.split('/').reverse().join('-');
    var de = new Date(dataend1);
    var end_dt = de.toISOString().substring(0,10);

    var CALENDAR_ID = 'my-id';
    var TOKEN = 'my-token';


    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
          xhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.teamup.com/'+CALENDAR_ID+'/events?_teamup_token='+TOKEN+'&startDate='+start_dt+'&endDate='+end_dt, true);
      xhttp.send();


    var e = document.getElementById('stampain').innerHTML = start_dt;
    var f = document.getElementById('stampafi').innerHTML = end_dt;


    }
    </script>
```

But output is undefined, ofcourse i'm missing something! Any solution?

Comment: What is the point of reformatting the string to ISO 8601, parsing it, then using *toISOString* and *substring* to generate exactly the same string again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the variable declaration inside the `loadDoc()` function.If declare as global .Its load on document load.At the time the value are not set.so there is undefined after button click.

```js
function loadDoc() {
// Define the data start
var datastart = document.getElementById('fromDate').value; // doesn't pick data
console.log(datastart)
// var datastart = '30/03/2017'; // manually
var datastart1 = datastart.split('/').reverse().join('-');
var ds = new Date(datastart1);
var start_dt = ds.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

// Define the data start
var dataend = document.getElementById('toDate').value; // doesn't pick data
// var dataend = '30/03/2017'; // manually
var dataend1 = dataend.split('/').reverse().join('-');
var de = new Date(dataend1);
var end_dt = de.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

var CALENDAR_ID = 'my-id';
var TOKEN = 'my-token';


  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.teamup.com/' + CALENDAR_ID + '/events?_teamup_token=' + TOKEN + '&startDate=' + start_dt + '&endDate=' + end_dt, true);
  xhttp.send();


  var e = document.getElementById('stampain').innerHTML = start_dt;
  var f = document.getElementById('stampafi').innerHTML = end_dt;


}
```

```html
<input id="fromDate" type="date">
<input id="toDate" type="date">

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Invia richiesta</button>

<p id="stampain"></p>
<p id="stampafi"></p>
<p id="stampali"></p>
```

Comment: Welcome @GiovanniDeStefanis .keep learning .we are with you..:-).